# Error during excel(xls) write operation

Tags: excel, robotframework

I have installed excel library from the below link:
[ExcelLibrary](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/)

Am trying to write data in excel using below code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ExtendedSelenium2Library
Library           ExcelLibrary


*** Testcases ***
Write Data in Excel
    Open Excel    D:\\01_Test_Cases\\testexcel.xls
    Put String To Cell    Sheet1    0    1    Test 
    Save Excel    D:\\01_Test_Cases\\testexcel.xls
```

When i execute this script, it shows following errors:

```
1)Indexerror: list index out of range
2)AttributeError: 'Nonetype'object has no attribute 'save'
```

Any workaround/suggestions on resolving this error would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

This  [ExcelLibrary](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/)is error prone , there is a thread which have some valuable discussion around it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/robotframework-users/GpAWczezNHk/kHWCWKA7YQcJ

i will list down steps here with formatted code

1) You need to edit your D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.py file

```
 def put_string_to_cell(self, sheetname, column, row, value):
            """
            Using the sheet name the value of the indicated cell is set to be the string given in the parameter.

            Arguments:
                    |  Sheet Name (string) | The selected sheet that the cell will be modified from.                                           |
                    |  Column (int)        | The column integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                    |
                    |  Row (int)           | The row integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                       |
                    |  Value (string)      | The string value that will be added to the specified sheetname at the specified column and row.   |
            Example:

            | *Keywords*           |  *Parameters*                                                           |
            | Open Excel           |  C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\ExcelRobotTest.xls  |     |     |        |
            | Put String To Cell   |  TestSheet1                                        |  0  |  0  |  Hello |

            """
            def put_string_to_cell(self, sheetname, column, row, value):

                if self.wb:
                    my_sheet_index = self.sheetNames.index(sheetname)
                if not self.tb:
                    self.wb.sheets()
                    self.tb = copy(self.wb)
                if self.tb:
                    plain = easyxf('')
                    self.tb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).write(int(row), int(column), value, plain)

def put_date_to_cell(self, sheetname, column, row, value):
        """
        Using the sheet name the value of the indicated cell is set to be the date given in the parameter.

        Arguments:
                |  Sheet Name (string)               | The selected sheet that the cell will be modified from.                                                            |
                |  Column (int)                      | The column integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                                     |
                |  Row (int)                         | The row integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                                        |
                |  Value (int)                       | The integer value containing a date that will be added to the specified sheetname at the specified column and row. |
        Example:

        | *Keywords*           |  *Parameters*                                                               |
        | Open Excel           |  C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\ExcelRobotTest.xls  |     |     |            |
        | Put Date To Cell     |  TestSheet1                                        |  0  |  0  |  12.3.1999 |

        """
        if self.wb:
            my_sheet_index = self.sheetNames.index(sheetname)
            # cell = self.wb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).cell(int(row), int(column))
            # if cell.ctype is XL_CELL_DATE:
            if not self.tb:
                self.wb.sheets()
                self.tb = copy(self.wb)
        if self.tb:
            print(value)
            # dt = value.split('.')
            # dti = [int(dt[2]), int(dt[1]), int(dt[0])]
            # print(dt, dti)
            ymd = datetime.strptime(value, '%d-%m-%Y')
            print(ymd)
            plain = easyxf('', num_format_str='d-M-yyyy')
            self.tb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).write(int(row), int(column), ymd, plain)


def put_number_to_cell(self, sheetname, column, row, value):
    """
    Using the sheet name the value of the indicated cell is set to be the number given in the parameter.

    Arguments:
            |  Sheet Name (string) | The selected sheet that the cell will be modified from.                                           |
            |  Column (int)        | The column integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                    |
            |  Row (int)           | The row integer value that will be used to modify the cell.                                       |
            |  Value (int)         | The integer value that will be added to the specified sheetname at the specified column and row.  |
    Example:

    | *Keywords*           |  *Parameters*                                                         |
    | Open Excel           |  C:\\Python27\\ExcelRobotTest\\ExcelRobotTest.xls  |     |     |      |
    | Put Number To Cell   |  TestSheet1                                        |  0  |  0  |  34  |

    """
    if self.wb:
        my_sheet_index = self.sheetNames.index(sheetname)
        # cell = self.wb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).cell(int(row), int(column))
        # if cell.ctype is XL_CELL_NUMBER:
    if not self.tb:
        self.wb.sheets()
        self.tb = copy(self.wb)
    if self.tb:
        plain = easyxf('')
        self.tb.get_sheet(my_sheet_index).write(int(row), int(column), float(value), plain)
```

2) After this go to D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExcelLibrary

run

```
python __init__.py
```

this will place compiled file into your ExcelLibrary package.

This code will help you to get resolve from error

1)Indexerror: list index out of range

however , i am still not able to save the file, and this code gives error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+b') or filename: u'test1.xls'
```

Suggestion :

its better to write your own custom library in python and use it in RF , if you want to know how to create a custom library , here is a link

http://learningbysimpleway.blogspot.in/2018/01/robotframework-have-rich-set-of_7.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will better write a custom library using python to support excel in xlsx format since there is limitation in existing excel library that it supports only xls format.